# toggle text fade when nav slides open and closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to have the nav links slowly fade in when you open the nav and disappear as soon as you click close on the nav. Currently it shows the links instantly and continues to display while they close.

Maybe jQuery toggle? or is there something in CSS I can do?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/mattmcgilton/pen/GRJVBxz

```
         <div class="col-4 d-flex flex-column align-items-end">
           <button id="open-btn" onclick="openNav()">Menu</button>
         </div>    


         <nav class="primary__nav">
            <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">close</a>
            <div class="container overlay-content">
              <ul>
                 <li>this is text 123</li>
                 <li>this is text 123</li>
                 <li>this is text 123</li>
                 <li>this is text 123</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
           </div>
         </nav>
```

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
  document.getElementById("open-btn").style.display = "none";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
  document.getElementById("open-btn").style.display = "block";
}
```

```
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  margin-top: 30px;

  ul {
    padding-left: 0;

    li {
      padding-bottom: 5rem;
    }
  }
}

.overlay a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  @include bodyLight();
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 70px;
  @include bodyBold();
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your requirement correctly you want have a timer slider in and out? if so you have to set the timer correctly in `'overlay` class. At present I have set it for 2 seconds.

```js
function openNav() {
  $(".overlay-content").fadeIn(2000);
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
  document.getElementById("open-btn").style.display = "none";

}

function closeNav() {
  $(".overlay-content").fadeOut(500);
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
  document.getElementById("open-btn").style.display = "block";

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

elementToFadeInAndOut {
  animation: fadeInOut 4s linear forwards;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 2s;
  /* here */
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display:none;
  ul {
    padding-left: 0;
    li {
      padding-bottom: 5rem;
    }
  }
}

.overlay a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  @include bodyLight();
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 70px;
  @include bodyBold();
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-4 d-flex flex-column align-items-end">
  <button id="open-btn" onclick="openNav()">Menu</button>
</div>


<nav class="primary__nav">
  <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">close</a>
    <div id="hide" class="container overlay-content">
      <ul>
        <li>this is text 123</li>
        <li>this is text 123</li>
        <li>this is text 123</li>
        <li>this is text 123</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I just the text to fade in. The overlay is correct.
I want the overlay to slide in like it currently does in the codepen, and then for the text to fade in once the overlay has come across, and then for the text to disappear when I click close on the menu. I don't want the text to slide in with the overlay. Get what I mean?

Comment: the `li` elements?

Comment: yeah the li elements

Comment: Yeah got it! I have updated my code for `fadein` I have given 3 seconds and for `fadeout` it is instant, let me know.

Comment: yeah that' what I'm looking for. Just strange on the first slide out the fade in on the text doesn't work, it's only after you open it, close it, and then open it again does the text fade in.

Comment: That is because the text is visible for the first time, you can set `display:none;` at first and then `fadeIn` work as expected. You can check now I have updated the code, since I have given time as 4 seconds it is waiting till nxt event occur, lower the timer and you can see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple fade-in animation which you can attach to any element via a class (`element.classList.add("fadeIn")`) on opening the nav and removing it (`element.classList.remove("fadeIn")`) on nav close. For hiding the text immediately, you can make a `hidden` class which will have `display: none` and use it in the same way.

```
.fadeIn{
  animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in;
}


@keyframes fadeIn{
  from {
    opacity:0
  }
  to {
    opacity:1
  }
}
```